# Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter

I am new in flutter and this null safety is making me difficult to use global variables.

[My code is here[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUiKH.png)

[Error is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev9gD.png)

Comment: You're  posting the error, not the code. Please the read the how to ask on stack overflow and post the code.

Comment: I have posted code too... click on 1 at the top. By the way this is my first time asking question in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using "!" on null variable. Be sure your variable is not null

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of solutions .
You can use !(this indicates, that Value will not be null )
(?. ) This means If value is null then return null else call its property (e.g object?. property )

Var myVar = someVariable ??  anotherVariable

This means If someVariable is null then Assign anotherVariable to myVar.

If this helps you , you can let me know :)

Comment: Yes, I figured out my mistake. I forgot to write await in front of createDatabase method. Thanks though.